# Make a field readonly on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

I have a WFS-T layer on GeoServer based on a shapefile. I want to set a specific field as a readonly field so that WFS-T operations cannot update that field. Is this possible? I couldn't find any information about this, how can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can, afaik none of the security systems are that fine grained

Answer (score 2):

The GeoFence plugin can make a single field read only, though I don't remember if that can be configured via the GUI, or needs using the REST API.